# AngularJS: show time from datetime

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular in a web application. I am showing some placed orders by users with following code. And this works just fine:

```
<div class="orderspresent" ng-cloak="">
<div class="roworders" style="margin-bottom:5px;" ng-controller="allorders" >
<div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat= "o in orders | orderBy:-o.orderID" ng-hide= "o.orderStatus=='done'" ng-hide="hidden" ng-class="{fade: startFade}">
<div class="sm-st clearfix">
 <div class="sm-st-info">
     <i class="fa fa-square"></i>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="{{o.orderID}}" ng-change="stateChanged({{o.orderID}})" ng-model="status"/>
 </div>
 <span>{{o.customerName}}</span>
 <p>{{o.orderDate | date:'h:mm'}}</p>
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat= "details in o.details">
     {{details.aantal}} x {{details.productTitle}}
     <div ng-if="details.extras">
      +{{details.extras}} 
     </div>
    </li>     
    <p class="totalprice">{{getTotal()}} euro</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But for each of these orders I want to show the time they got ordered. I tried using `{{o.orderDate | date:'h:mm'}}` but this doesn't seem to do anything... How can I only show for example: **10:06** or **12:10**?

**JSON Data**

```
[{"orderID":49,"customerID":61,"orderDate":"2015-05-06 10:03:05","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-05-06 10:30:05"}, ...]
```

Comment: what format do you get in the orderDate?Can you place that here so we can see what's coming and we can extract the time from it.

Comment: Maybe the property o.orderDate is not a date. Can you show the output of console.log(o.orderDate, typeof o.orderDate) please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the string you are passing into date filter is not valid ISO 8601 datetime string so the filter can't handle it. The closest to your `orderDate` strings applicable format would be something like `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ`. So you can either make your strings to look like `'2015-05-06T10:03:05'` or convert them to Date objects before passing to template: `new Date('2015-05-06 10:03:05')`.

Here is a little demo of the difference: http://plnkr.co/edit/t2nk1qS4SMvGPzeSi3eC?p=preview